# Reading all bytes of a BMP file in c++ and rotate picture

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++, bmp

I have a BMP file. I want to read all of its characters and rotate 90 cw the picture by these codes. But this codes works only on small pictures and colors were changed. I want use this codes for 800*686 pixels picture. this codes doesn't work for it. I think error is in reading file, because when I check the char vector of input file, after 59000 bytes, all of the chars in vector filled by 0 and the file didn't read compeletely:

```
struct pixel
{   char blue;
    char green;
    char red;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

        //Reading file and save all into data vector
        fstream fl("d://b.bmp");
        ofstream fl2("d://b2.bmp");
        fl.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
        streampos  length = fl.tellg();
        vector<char>  data(length);
        fl.seekg(0,ios::beg);
        fl.read(&data[0],length);


    //make a string of bytes based on characters in "file" vector ,to calculate file features
        byte intfile[54];
        for(int i=0;i<54;i++)
        {
            if (data[i]<0)
                intfile[i]=(256+data[i]);
            else
                intfile[i]=data[i];
        }

        //bpp is 2 bytes on 28,29 characters
        short int bpp = intfile[28] | intfile[29] << 8;

        //size of file is 4 bytes on 2,3,4,5 characters
        unsigned int size= intfile[2] | intfile[3] << 8 | intfile[4] << 16 | intfile[5] << 24;

        //offset of pixeles array is 4 bytes on 10,11,12,13 characters
        unsigned int offset= intfile[10] | intfile[11] << 8 | intfile[12] << 16 | intfile[13] << 24;

        //with is 4 bytes on 18,19,20,21 characters
        unsigned int with= intfile[18] | intfile[19] << 8 | intfile[20] << 16 | intfile[21] << 24;

        //height is 4 bytes on 22,23,24,25 characters
        unsigned int height= intfile[22] | intfile[23] << 8 | intfile[24] << 16 | intfile[25] << 24;

        //format of compression is 4 bytes on 30,31,32,33 characters
        unsigned int format= intfile[30] | intfile[31] << 8 | intfile[32] << 16 | intfile[33] << 24;


        //2D vector of pixels and filling it by data vector
        vector< vector<pixel> > arrpix;
        arrpix.resize(height);
        for(int j=0;j<height;j++)
            arrpix[j].resize(with);

        int ix=offset;
        for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<with;j++){
                arrpix[i][j].blue=data[ix++]; 
                arrpix[i][j].green=data[ix++];
                arrpix[i][j].red=data[ix++]; 
            }
            ix+=2;//padd
        }

        //2d new vector for making new rotated file
        vector< vector<pixel> > arrpix2;
        arrpix2.resize(with);
        for(int j=0;j<with;j++)
            arrpix2[j].resize(height);

        for(int i=0;i<with;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<height;j++){
                arrpix2[i][j].blue=arrpix[j][with-1-i].blue;
                arrpix2[i][j].green=arrpix[j][with-1-i].green;          
                arrpix2[i][j].red=arrpix[j][with-1-i].red;
            }   

        //newsize
        unsigned int news=(with*height*3)+54;//in rotation pad is not need because the new with is 800

        //makeing new vector
        vector<char>  data2(news);
        for(int i=0;i<news;i++)
            data2[i]=data[i];

        //change size
        data2[5] = (news >> 24) & 0xFF;
        data2[4] = (news >> 16) & 0xFF;
        data2[3] = (news >> 8) & 0xFF;
        data2[2] = news & 0xFF;


        //replace height and with
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            data2[18+i]=data[22+i];
            data2[22+i]=data[18+i];}
        ix=offset;
        //filling data by 2d new vector
        for(int i=0;i<with;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<height;j++){
                data2[ix++]=arrpix2[i][j].blue;
                data2[ix++]=arrpix2[i][j].green;
                data2[ix++]=arrpix2[i][j].red;
            }   
        }


        fl2.write(&data2[0],news);
        fl2.seekp(news,ios::beg);
        fl2.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why is data a vector<char> not a vector<byte>?

Comment: You have way to many "magic numbers"   What is 54?  What is 28? What is 29?   You should give them meaningful names, and probably calculate them rather than hard coding them.

Comment: @DaleWilson I examine this but , error accrued. because file.read works with char

Comment: 54 is header of bmp file based on wikipedia docs, I comment these numbers

Comment: I think these are not important.. Problem is reading all chars of byte but this code reads first 59000 chars and other chars in vector filled by 0.

Comment: Consider defining the header as a struct, then casting the pointer to char to be a pointer to header.  struct Header{....};  Header * header = reinterpret_cast<Header*>(&data[0]);

Comment: I agree these are not the problem.  These are things that could be fixed to help you find the problem.  (that's why I'm using comments, not an answer).

Comment: I checked it, but my problem didn't solved. My problem is all of chars of this byte (1.6 MB) didnt read and all of them didnt save into char vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reposition the file back to the beginning, to actually read the data I think you want:

```
 fl.seekg(0,ios::beg);
```

rather than

```
 fl.seekg(length,ios::beg);
```

edit:

After the read add this code:

```
if(f1.eof())
{
   std::cerr << "Error reading file."
             << " Requested " << length << " bytes."
             << " Read " << f1.gcount() << bytes."
             << std::endl;
}
```

That should tell you how big your code thinks the file is (verify against actual file size), and whether f1 thinks the read went well.

---

Also you should open the file in binary mode by using the ios::binary mode flag when you open the file.